# Finding NSAttributedString's attribute below the tap position of the view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-text, nsattributedstring

How can i find attribute of the text (it's NSAttributedString where each sentence have it's unique atribute) below the tap position of the view, while using NSAttributedString with Core Text Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Core Text directly, not a text view?  I assume you have a `CTFrameRef`.  You can get the lines and the line origins using `CTFrameGetLines()` and `CTFrameGetLineOrigins()`.  Find the right line based on its origin and then use `CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition()` to get the string index.

Comment: I will use core text inside scroll View, i am kind of following this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/how-to-create-a-simple-magazine-app-with-core-text. What i am trying to achieve its a scrollable non-editable view with text divided to sentences internally in NSAttributedString and each sentence assigned unique tag. I want to be able to tap a sentence, then it should be scrolled to the center of my view and to emphasize clicked sentence by changing it's visual style (font, color).